# ABC SMC: How do weights scale proportionally with number of parameters

Tags: bayesian, model-selection, monte-carlo, approximate-bayesian-computation, sequential-monte-carlo

Having some problems with the ABC SMC algorithm. I'm trying to implement the methods taken from here: [Simulation-based model selection for dynamical systems in systems and population biology](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/26/1/104/182571#supplementary-data)

### How do weights scale down with increasing parameters?

I am having problems with this part of the weight calculation, w(m ,theta) . My current implementation is giving a higher weighting to particles with more parameters, which should not be the case.

[image]
[image]

In the function S, KP is a perturbation kernel that describes the probability of particle having come from the previous population. A small KP makes the denominator small, and therefore the overall weighting high.

[image]

[image]

Is it not the case that the more parameters that are present, the smaller KP becomes? I can't see anywhere in the paper that describes how the weighting is adjusted according to the number of parameters.

I've written a small example to illustrate the problem, and removed parts involving model perturbation that are included in the figures. Model a has one parameter, model b has six parameters. We assume they are all accepted and given weights. What am I missing to make the weighting proportional to the number of parameters?

```py
def get_pdf_uniform(lower_bound, upper_bound, x):
    if (x > upper_bound) or (x < lower_bound):
        print(x)
        print(upper_bound)
        print(lower_bound)
        return 0.0

    else:
        return (1 / (upper_bound - lower_bound))


def weight_problem_example():
    # Two priors, one small one large
    prior_a = [[1, 5]]
    model_a = "a"

    prior_b = [[1, 5], [1, 5], [1, 5], [1, 5], [1, 5], [1, 5]]
    model_b = "b"

    # Previous population had equal weights
    prev_weight_a = 0.5
    prev_weight_b = 0.5

    # Sampled parameters are within prior range
    particle_a_params = [np.random.uniform(x[0], x[1]) for x in prior_a]
    particle_b_params = [np.random.uniform(x[0], x[1]) for x in prior_b]

    particle_a_prev_params = [np.random.uniform(x[0], x[1]) for x in prior_a]
    particle_b_prev_params = [np.random.uniform(x[0], x[1]) for x in prior_b]

    packed_a = [prior_a, particle_a_params, particle_a_prev_params, prev_weight_a, model_a]
    packed_b = [prior_b, particle_b_params, particle_b_prev_params, prev_weight_b, model_b]


    particles = []
    particles = particles + [packed_a for x in range(1000)]
    particles =  particles + [packed_b for x in range(1000)]

    model_a_weights = []
    model_b_weights = []
    for part in particles:
        # unpack particle data
        prior = part[0]
        params = part[1]
        prev_params = part[2]
        prev_weight = part[3]
        model = part[4]

        # Numerator
        particle_prior_prob = 1
        for idx, p in enumerate(params):
            particle_prior_prob = particle_prior_prob * get_pdf_uniform(prior[idx][0], prior[idx][1], p)

        # Assume equal model probability
        particle_prior_prob = particle_prior_prob * 1


        # Denominator, assuming we only have two particles
        s = 0
        for theta in particles:
            if theta[4] == model:
                theta_prior = part[0]
                theta_params = part[1]
                theta_prev_params = part[2]
                theta_prev_weight = part[3]
                theta_model = part[4]

                k_prob = 1
                for theta_idx, theta_p in enumerate(theta_prev_params):
                    # get parameter kernel pdf
                    k_prob = k_prob * get_pdf_uniform(
                        theta_p - theta_prior[theta_idx][0]*2, 
                        theta_p + theta_prior[theta_idx][1]*2, 
                        params[theta_idx])                    

                # print(s)
                s += (theta_prev_weight * k_prob)

        part_weight = particle_prior_prob/s

        if model == "a":
            model_a_weights.append(part_weight)

        if model == "b":
            model_b_weights.append(part_weight)

    print(np.mean(model_a_weights))
    print(np.mean(model_b_weights))
```